# add items in a combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add items from a file saved in path "C:\Users\se72497\Desktop" which contains in the 1st column of the sheet called "Departamentos" a series of values I want to add in the Combobox.

My combobox receive the name of dept.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Dim filename As Workbook
        Set filename = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\se72497\Desktop\Tablas_Macro.xlsx")
        With filename.Sheets("Departamentos")
            dept.List = Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value)
        End With
End Sub
```

I've tried to execute this code but it returns me a run-time error:

[image]

**Why vba returns me this error?**

Comment: `.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value` - `.Value` shouldn't be inside the parentheses. You're trying to use the `Value` of the cell, not the cell itself, as the 2nd argument of the `Range` call.

Comment: Can you write the code to see an example of how I should write it?

Answer (score 2):

The `.Value` is in the wrong place. (Or you could say that the parenthesis is in the wrong place). Correcting this, you have:

```
.Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
```

With your current code, `.Value` is *within* the `Range` call, so you're trying to use the *value* of the cell, not the *cell itself*, as the 2nd argument.

You want it outside.

Otherwise, if the last cell's value is "foo", then your code is equivalent to

```
 Range("A2", "foo")
```

which is most certainly not what you want.

Answer (score -1):

So when you click pn your combo box data will get loaded,

' Pre-requisties name the cell A2 with variable rstart

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Departamentos")
Dim i As Integer: i = 0
Dim lRow As Long
Dim sAddress As String

On Error GoTo errhandling
If Me.nameofcombobox.Value = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Select value to continue!"
Else
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("Departamentos").Rows.Count
        'name the cell a2 as rstart
        Do Until .Range("rStart").Offset(0, i).Value = Me.nameofcombobox.Value
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        sAddress = .Range("rStart").Offset(0, i - 1).Address
        .Range(sAddress & ":" & Left(sAddress, 4) & lRow).Value = .Range(sAddress & ":" & Left(sAddress, 4) & lRow).Value
    End With
End If
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "Completed without errors", vbInformation, "Success"
```

FunctionOutput:
    Set ws = Nothing

Exit Sub

errhandling:
     MsgBox "The following error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
     Resume FunctionOutput

```
 End Sub
```

Comment: There are some issues with this code. If combobox doesn't have a value, you will get a msgbox saying: **Select value to continue** and then another msgbox saying: **Completed without errors**. Also, is `sStart` a named range? Can't see where OP has specified that? You haven't formatted your code properly so it's hard to read

Comment: Yes,only if you select the dropdown value  you can proceed to next level,that is the reason I had added that line.  For named range I had mentioned as prerequistes in the code with the comment. My way of coding is ususally nming a variable and proceeding.  Please downgrade without seeing it properly